# variable not recognized php

Tags: php, xampp, dreamweaver

I have a php file with a form to login.
I have other php file index.php, and i want that when i do login i go to this page: index.php.
So i have this code:

```
<?php
if(($login) and ($pass))
 {


    ?>

              <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W2C//DD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"               "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml2-transitional.dsd">
              <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1312/xhtml">
              <head>
              <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
              <title>Untitled Document</title>
              </head>

              <body>
              <h1>Header</h1>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <h1>Heeloo</h1>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <h1>Footer</h1>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
              </body>
              </html>

              <?php
     }
              else 
              {
                 echo "you didnt login";
              }

              ?>
```

I have other php file to validate the login, i have this code:

```
<?php 

    if(($_POST['user'] == "john") && ($_POST['password'] == "123"))
    {
        setcookie("login",$_POST['user']);
        setcookie("pass",$_POST['password']);
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
    else

       echo "you dont have permission";

    ?>
```

I got this error: 
Notice: Undefined variable: login in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\cookie\index.php on line 2

I think its because im using $login and $pass variables in index.php file and because these variables are from the other file is not recognizing.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't post the other file, so this is a guess: try using `$_REQUEST['login']` and `$_REQUEST['pass']` instead of `$login` and `$pass`

Comment: Just a point, you should never put a password in a cookie. It can easily be captured.

Answer (score 0):

You set both $login and $pass as cookies. You have to read them in the index.php script, since they're not read back to your code automatically.

But instead of that, it's much better to use sessions. First, check if the login and password are ok. The result of this will be `$_SESSION['auth']` being set to true or false. Of course, 'auth' is a suggestion, change it to the identifier you prefer:

```
// Initialize session control.
session_start();

// Check username and password. The function CheckCredentials() represents 
// your logic on checking if they are ok.
if(CheckCredentials($login, $pass))
  $_SESSION['auth'] = true;
else
  $_SESSION['auth'] = false;
```

Then in your index.php script use `session_start()` again (that will enable the session data to be "seen" by current script) and modify your initial if:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['auth'])
{
```

This is more complicated in real code, but this is the general idea.

Comment: hmmm ok thanks, im starting studying php, i´ll go see if i can find something about session!